# not able to Deserialize xml into object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am having following peice of code ,where in i am trying to serialize and deserailize object of  StringResource class.
Please note Resource1.stringXml =  its coming from resource file.If i pass strelemet.outerXMl i get the object from Deserialize object ,but if i pass Resource1.stringXml i am getting following exception

{"< STRING xmlns=''> was not expected."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StringResource str = new StringResource();
        str.DELETE = "CanDelete";
        str.ID= "23342";
        XmlElement strelemet = SerializeObjectToXmlNode (str);

        StringResource strResourceObject = DeSerializeXmlNodeToObject<StringResource>(Resource1.stringXml);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static T DeSerializeXmlNodeToObject<T>(string objectNodeOuterXml)
    {
        try
        {
            TextReader objStringsTextReader = new StringReader(objectNodeOuterXml);
            XmlSerializer stringResourceSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T),string.Empty);
            return (T)stringResourceSerializer.Deserialize(objStringsTextReader);
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public static XmlElement SerializeObjectToXmlNode(object obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                xmlNameSpace.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
                XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                writerSettings.CloseOutput = false;
                writerSettings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                writerSettings.Indent = false;

                writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, writerSettings);

                XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, obj, xmlNameSpace);
                writer.Close();
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                XmlDocument serializeObjectDoc = new XmlDocument();
                serializeObjectDoc.Load(memoryStream);

                return serializeObjectDoc.DocumentElement;
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class StringResource
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string DELETE;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ID;
}
```

<  STRING ID="1" DELETE="True" />

Comment: can you include your XML string too?? seems there some problem in XML....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is a name mismatch in your XML root node and your class

```
< STRING ID="1" DELETE="True" />  -- STRING here
public class StringResource       -- StringResource Here.
```

Add **xmlroot** attribute to your class, and will see what happens

```
[XmlRoot( "STRING " )]
public class StringResource 
{ 
    [XmlAttribute] 
    public string DELETE; 
    [XmlAttribute] 
    public string ID; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wel it's obvious `Resource1.stringXml` does not contain a correct XML which could be deserialized to a `StringResource` object. The XML should look like this:

```
<StringResource DELETE="CanDelete" ID="23342" />
```